# Настройка Xdebug в виртуальной машине

Tags: php, xdebug

Использую windows 10. На виртуалбоксе ubuntu 22.04. В windows запущен phpshtorm и Chrome. Не могу настроить Xdebug что бы ловил браузер. В Chrome расширение установлено и включено. Обычный запуск php файла через Xdebug работает(пункт в phpshtorm debug) брейкпойты отрабатывают.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки Php.ini

zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.4
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_autostart=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил настройки php.ini и заработало. Так же убрал в virtualbox проброс порта 9003.

zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_autostart=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.discover_client_host=false